# how to iterate in a result of selector with jquery

Tags: jquery, selector

i've some checkbox and i want to change background color of them when are selected more than one checkbox. I'm trying from this way:

```
var checked = $("input[@type=checkbox]:checked");
$('tr[name="' + checked.attr('name') + '"]').each(function() {
                        $(this).css('background-color', '#0000DD');
                    });
```

only the first selected changes is color and the other selected no, can you help me? does selector give in output only the first?

SOLVED IN THIS WAY:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").parents('tr').css('background-color', '#0000DD');
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery is not XPath. Omit the `@`. Also, the `.css` method applies the style to all elements ib the collection, so you can omit `.each`.

```
var checked = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked");
$('tr[name="' + checked.attr('name') + '"]').css('background-color', '#0000DD');
```

Edit: I think that you misunderstand the method logic.
If you want to change the style of the container `<tr>` element, you have to loop through every element in the checkbox collection, and run some code on it:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').css('background-color', '#0000DD');
});
```

Comment: @JackTurky Updated answer 1 hour ago, after looking at your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9283273/how-to-change-color-of-a-row-in-a-table). Your current method (using `.parents()` is inferior to the recommende `.closest()` method. `.closest()` selects the nearest parent, and stops looking further. `parents()` traverses the whole tree, and stops at the top of the document.

Answer (score 0):

.attr will only return the attribute of the first matched element. You have to traverse the result of the first selector (and also select the attribute without an @):

```
var checked = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
    $('tr[name="' + $(this).attr('name') + '"]').css('background-color', '#0000DD');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `[@type=checkbox]` by `[type=checkbox]` or just ':checkbox`. Try this.

```
$("input:checkbox:checked").each(function(){
     $('tr[name="' + this.name + '"]').each(function() {
          $(this).css('background-color', '#0000DD');
     });
});
```